# disable any field by selecting close value of spinner

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to disable any `EditText` by selecting the any particular value of spinner. If Yes, then How?? Kindly Guide i'll thankful to you.

Comment: what you have tried to archive this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int id, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (id == mySlctNum)
                {
                    ediTxt.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

Comment: i have 3 options in spinner 1.open, 2.closed, 3.all    what will i assign in if condition instead of nySlctNum??? i used adapter<Charsequence> in spinner.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can set the editText to `setEnabled(false);` whenever you select a particular item of a spinner and even you can set the edittext to be invisible too by setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); and setVisibility(View.GONE); . If you could edit your question with more details, there would be chances of having my answer edited.